# What year was The Warriors (1979)  first shown on TV or cable?

Tags: the-warriors

Is there a way to figure out the year the movie [The Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_%28film%29) (1979) was first shown on TV or cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [webpage](http://80smemories.com/2011/07/the-cult-classic-the-warriors-first-time-on-tvhbo-1983/), The Warriors was first time on TV in **1983**.

Comment: I am pretty sure it showed on the Z channel before 1983, but only on the basis of personal recollection.